# Google authenticator QR code scan work in any mobile

Tags: google-authenticator

I'm using google authenticator code for 2FA in my website. Can able to check QR code is scanned from registered mobile number? Now, i can able to scan the code from any mobile

Answer (score 1):

Google Authenticator does not perform network operations of any kind. The QR code is merely a way to easily seed the TOTP algorithm.

To answer your question directly, no, there is no way to either log the number of the device it was scanned from nor is there a way to restrict which devices can scan it.